# Update statement is not working, Entity framework installed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
       #region PutAktivnost
    [HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Aktivnost))]
    [Route("api/Aktivnosti/PutAktivnost/{aktivnost}")]
    public IHttpActionResult PutAktivnost([FromBody] AktivnostEditVM aktivnost)
    {

        Aktivnost put=db.Aktivnost.Where(a => a.AktivnostID == aktivnost.AktivnostId).FirstOrDefault();
        put.Naziv=aktivnost.naziv;
        db.Aktivnost.Update(put);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();

    }
    #endregion
```

I really need help with this.. Everything is OK, but when I write `db.Aktivnost.Update(put)` the Update method is not recognized. Error is:

> "DbSet does not contain a definition for 'Update' and no
>   extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type
>   'DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)"

This is that part:

```
public partial class MoneySaverEntities : DbContext
{
    public MoneySaverEntities()
        : base("name=MoneySaverEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Aktivnost> Aktivnost { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AutorizacijskiToken> AutorizacijskiToken { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Korisnik> Korisnik { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Trosak> Trosak { get; set; }
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: if db has change tracking enabled (it has by default), the code without the Update() statement should work. ChangeTracking automatically sets the state of attached objects to modified once they are changed. If ChangeTracking is disabled, you'll have to set the entity (or property) state to modified manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead you can try this code, make sure you have a new instance of your context otherwise it will show you an error.

```
public IHttpActionResult PutAktivnost([FromBody] AktivnostEditVM aktivnost)
{
     db.Entry(aktivnost).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
     db.SaveChanges();
     return Ok();

}
```